# Horizontally aligned divs working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-float

I am running into this problem with how `div`s align in Firefox and Chrome.
I need two `div`s with undefined widths to be side by side in a wrapping `div`. The idea is to produce a long scrollbar full of content.

The problem I am having is that in Firefox 22.0 the `div`s end up stacking while in Chrome 28.0 it is working fine. Here are two screenshots of the problem.

### Firefox

[image]

### Chrome

[image]

Is this a Firefox quirk? Is it an issue that can be fixed with a `display` or `clear` property?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4GHUS/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of floating the elements to the left, you can use `display: inline-block;` with `white-space: nowrap;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GHUS/3/)

```
#wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    border:2px solid red;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#images {
    height:200px;
    border:4px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#thumbs {
    height:100px;
    border:4px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `float: left` use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align-top` in both the child divs style class.

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly could you be use a vertical-align: top to the image properties to align images to the top of div container